# getting a warning concerning UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn

Tags: uiviewanimation-curve

I just updated my app because of a warning and now I get the following error
Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum UIViewAnimationCurve' to different enumeration type 'UIAnimationOptions' (aka 'enum UIViewAnimationOptions')
This is the code I use.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{arrow2.titleLabel.alpha = 1,arrow2.center = CGPointMake(160, 120);        ball.center = CGPointMake(160, 120);text.alpha = 0;} completion:^ (BOOL completed) {}         ];
```

what do I need to do to get rid of this warning/
Thanks

Found the answer added Option to code UIViewAnamation**Option**CurveEaseIn took care of it.

Comment: You should be using UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn instead.
UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn is part of a different enum used in other methods.Try this.